# Looking for a collection of audio samples comparing German accents

Tags: accent, audio

I am looking for something a collection of audio samples suitable for comparing the various German accents.

(This wonderful [collection](http://www.learningportuguese.co.uk/audio/compare-accents.html) of audio recordings by speakers of various Portuguese accents, all reading the exact same passage, is an example of what I'm after for German.)

PS: I'm aware of Deutsche Welle's [Dialektatlas](http://www.dw.de/deutsch-lernen/dialektatlas/s-8150), which is very interesting in its own right, but I find it difficult to compare accents with it.

---

**EDIT:** I want to stress that I am looking for a comparison of *accents*, not of *dialects*.  Notice that the example I cited, comparing Portuguese, all the speakers are reading *the same text*.  This means that *difference in word choice and word ordering has been eliminated from the comparison, by design.*  The premise of such a comparison is, of course, that, once one removes the difference in word choice and word ordering, some audible difference still remains.  It is *that* residual difference that I am interested in.  I cannot believe that this has not been studied at all, but I can find *absolutely nothing* about it.  The primary reason, I think, is that studies and comparisons of German dialects completely overwhelm any list of search results.

Comment: In my Google searches I tried various combinations of *Akzent*, *Vergleich*, and *Hörbeispiele*...  I could use better keywords...

Answer (score 3):

How did you search at Google?

I tried it with http://www.google.de/search?q=mp3+dialekte+deutsche and found some hits.

Technical remark: Google forwards me alqays the the German version of Google. Perhaps thats a reason, why I get more results.

- A short history: http://www.studentstories.de/folge31-deutsche-dialekte
- [Mundart-Tonbeispiele (universtity Marburg)](http://staff-www.uni-marburg.de/~naeser/dial-aud.htm)
- [Deutschen Historischen Museum](http://www.dhm.de/lemo/suche/audios.html) ( See sound examples with 'Dialekt...')
- [Youtube has also some examples](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=deutsche%20dialekte).
- [regionalsprache.de](http://www.regionalsprache.de/ton-stand-der-Bearbeitung.aspx) makes a reference to DiWa `derzeit in DiWA abrufbar: 3700  Aufnahmen der Wenkersätze` (3700 recording available) - but I didn't find it in the map (probably a problem with my Browser).